# Error Setting Azure Key Vault Access Policy in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am attempting to set the access policy for a key vault I created in Azure via PowerShell.  The command I am using is

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName <key vault name> -UserPrincipalName <microsoft account> -PermissionsToKeys all
```

When I run that command I get the error.

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy : Sequence contains more than one element
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName <key vault name> -UserPr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.SetAzureKeyVaultAccessPolicy
```

Any ideas on what this error means and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Could you please run this script `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` to check your Azure PowerShell version?

Comment: The version is 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using variables for providing either parameter(-VaultName or -UserPrincipalName); make sure it’s passing only one value at a time.

If you’re working with multiple vaults or multiple user principals; you must use a for each look to accomplish your task.